# Limiting a draggable element within a container

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have made a div draggable without using the jquery ui library, but I want to make the draggable box, not to leave its container.

Here is my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KdehU/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dragging = null;

    $(document.body).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if ($dragging) {
            $dragging.offset({
                top: e.pageY,
                left: e.pageX
            });
        }
    });

    $(document.body).on("mousedown", ".box", function (e) {
        $dragging = $(e.target);
    });

    $(document.body).on("mouseup", function (e) {
        $dragging = null;
    });
});​
```

How to do this? Please NOTE, I am not using **JQUERY UI**.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that...

- the left position of the box is greater than the left position of the container, and
- the right position of the box *(left position + box width)* is less than right position of the container, and
- the top position of the box is greater than the top position of the container, and
- the bottom position of the box *(top position + box height)* is less than bottom position of the container

---

http://jsfiddle.net/KdehU/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dragging = null;

    var container = $('#container'),
        c_t = container.offset().top,
        c_l = container.offset().left,
        c_b = c_t + container.height(),
        c_r = c_l + container.width();

    $(document.body).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if ($dragging) {
            var width = $dragging.width();
            var height = $dragging.height();

            var new_y = (e.pageY > c_t && (e.pageY + height) < c_b) ? e.pageY : undefined;
            var new_x = (e.pageX > c_l && (e.pageX + width) < c_r) ? e.pageX : undefined;

            $dragging.offset({
                top: new_y,
                left: new_x
            });
        }
    });

    $(document.body).on("mousedown", ".box", function (e) {
        $dragging = $(e.target);
    });

    $(document.body).on("mouseup", function (e) {
        $dragging = null;
    });
});
```